# Grails, connecting to S3 using jets3t

Tags: grails, amazon-s3, quartz-scheduler, jets3t

I am trying to connect to Amazon S3 Buckets using "JetS3t", I am also using Quartz plugin,
I have a job in grails-app/jobs, in which I like to access S3, but I get an error in the socond line:

```
AWSCredentials awsCredentials = new AWSCredentials(grailsApplication.config.s3.accessKey, grailsApplication.config.s3.secretKey)

S3Service s3Service = new RestS3Service(awsCredentials)
```

here is the error:

```
ERROR listeners.ExceptionPrinterJobListener  - Exception occurred in job: null
Message: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/jamesmurty/utils/XMLBuilder
```

Do I have to create a service and set up my S3 there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def aws_credentials = {
        return new AWSCredentials(grailsApplication.config.aws.accessKey, grailsApplication.config.aws.secretKey)
    }

    def s3_service = {
        return new RestS3Service(aws_credentials())
    }

    def test = {
        def buckets = s3_service().listAllBuckets()
        System.out.println("How many buckets to I have in S3? " + myBuckets.length);
    }
```

And of course you don't have to put the objects in multiple methods, use them however you want.

Also make sure you have these imports:

```
import org.jets3t.service.impl.rest.httpclient.RestS3Service
import org.jets3t.service.security.AWSCredentials
```